# Timesatmp to years ago conversion php

Tags: php, timestamp

Below is the code that converts timestamp into "X" years ago....
but if i enter current time stamp its not function properly..please help

This is the function that converts the timestamp

```
<?php
    function timeAgo($time_ago){
    $cur_time   = time();
    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
    $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
    $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
    $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
    $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
    $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
    $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
    // Seconds
    if($seconds <= 60){
        echo "$seconds seconds ago";
    }
    //Minutes
    else if($minutes <=60){
        if($minutes==1){
            echo "one minute ago";
        }
        else{
            echo "$minutes minutes ago";
        }
    }
    //Hours
    else if($hours <=24){
        if($hours==1){
            echo "an hour ago";
        }else{
            echo "$hours hours ago";
        }
    }
    //Days
    else if($days <= 7){
        if($days==1){
            echo "yesterday";
        }else{
            echo "$days days ago";
        }
    }
    //Weeks
    else if($weeks <= 4.3){
        if($weeks==1){
            echo "a week ago";
        }else{
            echo "$weeks weeks ago";
        }
    }
    //Months
    else if($months <=12){
        if($months==1){
            echo "a month ago";
        }else{
            echo "$months months ago";
        }
    }
    //Years
    else{
        if($years==1){
            echo "one year ago";
        }else{
            echo "$years years ago";
        }
    }
    }

    ?>
```

This is where it is called from

```
 <?php
      $curenttime="2015-06-1 4:35";
      $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
      echo timeAgo($time_ago);
    ?>
```

Output

```
4weeks
```

Comment: what is the question, need to be clarified

Comment: That looks about right, what do you expect to see? It's 1st July 2015 today, 1st June 2015 was 30 days ago, which is 4 weeks (rounded)

Comment: if  input current tym i.e "2015-07-9 4:35"...it should show "just now"...it is not showing that

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like it works.

```
$curenttime="2015-06-1 4:35";
```

That is the first June, today is the first July, so the date you entered was 4 weeks ago.